# eclipse CDT: error while loading shared library

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, shared

I have an eclipse c++ project with two shared libraries. I've included the names of the libraries and their paths under the project settings. The project builds fine, but I cannot run it:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libxxx.so.0.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

- Do I have to set the ld_library_path variable to run the project in eclipse?
- Do I have to set the ld_library_path variable if i want to run the application in the console?
- Is there a method, i can use to avoid having to set the ld_library_path?

Comment: You may need `-rpath=dir` linker option.